# (HTML5) Need to make some images transparent, and others not

Tags: css, html, image, opacity

I'm actually a brand-new coder, just starting on HTML (started yesterday) and I'm having a bit of trouble with something that I can't quite seem to find out how to do. I used CSS to make an image transparent on my main page, but unfortunately, it makes all the other images transparent as well, despite the fact that all the others are meant to be opaque. Here's the source code for my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
     background-image: url("bg.png");
     background-color: #cccccc;
}
  h1   {color:green}
  p    {color:blue}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
header {
            position:fixed;
            top:0;
            background-color:#333;
            opacity: 0.4;
            width:100%;
            height:40px;
            padding:20px;
            text-align:center;
        }

        footer {
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color:#333;
            opacity: 0.4;
            position: fixed;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #main{
            padding-top:100px;
            text-align:center;
        }
img {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1.4;
}
</style>
</head>
<title>Jordan's Test Site (iCarlos)</title>
<body center>
 <header> Deal with it B)</header>
<div id="main">
 <p><img src="giphy.gif" alt=Deal with it! style="width:500px;height:273px"></p>
 <p>Hello! I am a website. Testing, testing, 1 2 3.</p>
 <p><a href="yep.html"><img src="deal-with-it.png" alt=Clic! style="width:450px;height:80px"></a></p>
 <p><a href="table.html">Click here to go to the table!</a></p>
</div>
<footer>
<p><a href="index.html"><img src="home.png" alt=source style=width:124;height:124></a></p>
</footer>
</body /center>
```

Thanks for the help, guys!

Comment: `opacity: 1.4` is not a valid value.  Opacity values range from 0 (transparent) to 1 (solid color).

Comment: be more specific while adding opacity `img.classname`

Comment: add a class for image then give so that it applies for that only `img.classname {
    opacity: 0.4;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to define a class for transparent images (your current selector `img` adds the opacity rule to ALL the images) and then add these rules:

```
img.transparent {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
img.transparent:hover {
    opacity: 1; // no point in going higher than 1 here
}
```

Then in the HTML, just add the class to those images you want transparent:

```
<img src="image.jpg" class="transparent" alt="" />
```

Comment: 2`..` after img on 2nd

Comment: Much appreciated! Short, sweet, to the point, and completely worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your specific image.

Right now, `img` selects the tag `img` and not a specific image.  You need to select an additional attribute to specify which image.  You can do that by adding a `class` attribute, an `id` attribute or using your existing attributes like so (though I wouldn't generally recommend this):

```
 img[alt=Clic!] {
   opacity: 0.4;
 }
 img[alt=Clic!]:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First option**: Give the image an ID (or class, or select by its alt-attribute as Josh Burgess makes clear) and add a style rule to reflect its opacity

*HTML*

```
<img src="giphy.gif" id="transparent-image" alt="Deal with it!" style="width:500px;height:273px">
```

*CSS*

```
#transparent-image {opacity: 0.4;}
```

You can also use classes. Classes can be used on multiple elements in a document. **IDs should never be used multiple times!** A passport is for one individual in the whole wide world. Similarly, an ID is for only one element in your HTML. In your cases it might be useful to use a class so that you can have multiple transparent items with only one class:

```
.transparent-image {opacity: 0.4;}
```

Now, when you add the following HTML to an element, it will have this opacity value:

```
class="transparent-image"
```

For example:

```
<img src="giphy.gif" class="transparent-image" alt="Deal with it!" style="width:500px;height:273px">
```

**Second option**: Use inline styling

```
<img src="giphy.gif" alt="Deal with it!" style="width:500px;height:273px;opacity:0.4">
```

The first option is the best. Inline styles should not be used unless it concerns small chunks that are smaller than an added class would be. In your case, get rid of the inline styles all together and use stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're targetting every single `img`tag in your HTML.

You have two easy ways to target only some images :

- Add a class to the images you want to make transparent, in your HTML, and target that class in CSS

Example HTML :

```
<img class="transparent" src="..." alt="...">
```

And in the CSS :

```
img.transparent{
    opacity: 0.5; /* Example, set it to whatever you want */
}
```

- You can also keep your HTML structure and target your element more precisely with CSS

Let's say that you want to change the opacity of the `img` that are contained in  the `header`, and not the opacity of the images that are not in the `header`, you could do this :

```
header img{ 
    opacity: 0.5; /* Example, set it to whatever you want */
}
```

This is very basic in CSS and I recommand that you read a few tutorials, all of this should be covered.

Here is a good tutorial for beginners : http://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can target different images with a CSS class:

```css
img {
  
  opacity: 0.8;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  }

img:hover {
  
  opacity: 1;
  }

.transparent {
  
  opacity: 0.2;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  }

.transparent:hover {
  
  opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" class="transparent"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" class="transparent"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" class="transparent"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000"><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000">
```

Hope this helps!